# How to identify quadric surface and quadric curves?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, quadrics

I was given this equation $f(x,y) = x^2 + 4xy + y^2 - 2x + 2y + 1$

I'm trying to find the quadric surface when $f(x,y) = z$ and the quadric curve when $f(x,y) = 0$. I started with the quadric surface and set x to a constant and found that yz makes a parabola, set y to a constant and found that xz makes a parabola. But because there are mixed variables, I'm not sure what to make of it when I set z to a constant. I used Geogebra and Desmos to check my answer, I'm pretty sure the last part makes a hyperbola and the quadric curve is a hyperbola as well, but I don't know how to prove it.

$z = c : x^2 + 4xy + y^2 - 2x + 2y = c - 1$

What makes this a hyperbola? All the videos I found online doesn't go over examples with mixed variables, how I do a identify these when mixed variables are present?

EDIT: So I'm pretty sure the quadric surface is a hyperbolic paraboloid.

Comment: $-3(\frac{(\frac{((x+1)-(y-1))}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{\sqrt{3}^2}-\frac{(\frac{((x+1)+(y-1))}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{1^2}-1)=0$ and $-\frac{z-3}{3}=\frac{(\frac{((x+1)-(y-1))}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{\sqrt{3}^2}-\frac{(\frac{((x+1)+(y-1))}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{1^2}$

Answer (score 1):

For any quadric, and this includes conics, you can rewrite the expression as a linear combination of squared linear terms and linear terms. This amounts to applying an affine transformation, which doesn’t change the nature of the quadric, to a coordinate system in which the equation has one of the standard forms that doesn’t include any cross-terms.

Taking first the level set $f(x,y)=0$, by repeatedly completing the square we can rewrite the equation as $$(x+2y-1)^2-3(y-1)^2+3=0.$$ This has the form $X^2-3Y^2+c=0$, which is a hyperbola.

We can analyze $f(x,y)-z=0$ in a similar fashion and can reuse most of the preceding work. We end up with $$(x+2y-1)^2-3(y-1)^2-(z-1) = 0.$$ This equation has the form $X^2-Y^2=Z$. If you don’t happen to recognize this as a hyperbolic paraboloid, you can analyze this simplified equation in the way that you describe in your question.

Effectively, what we’re doing here is computing the *spectrum* of the (homogenized) quadric, which uniquely determines its type.